# Get the static type from generic runtime type

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

Try to get the `ApiResponse<T>` static TS generic type from the generic runtime type created by `io-ts`. No information in [official documentation](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/blob/master/index.md#generic-types)

Expect type:

```
// runtime type
const ApiResponseCodec = <C extends t.Mixed>(codec: C) =>
  t.type({
    code: t.string,
    message: t.union([t.string, t.undefined]),
    result: codec,
  });

// expect type
type ApiResponse<T> = {
  code: string;
  message: string | undefined;
  result: T;
}
```

Complete code:

```
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';
import * as E from 'fp-ts/lib/Either';
import * as t from 'io-ts';

const ArticleDTOCodec = t.type({
  id: t.number,
  title: t.string,
});
type ArticleDTO = t.TypeOf<typeof ArticleDTOCodec>;

const PaginationResultCodec = <C extends t.Mixed>(codec: C) =>
  t.type({
    resultList: codec,
    totalItem: t.number,
  });

type PaginationResult<C extends t.Mixed> = t.TypeOf<ReturnType<typeof PaginationResultCodec<C>>>;

const ApiResponseCodec = <C extends t.Mixed>(codec: C) =>
  t.type({
    code: t.string,
    message: t.union([t.string, t.undefined]),
    result: codec,
  });

// Does not infer the type correctly.
type ApiResponse<C extends t.Mixed> = t.TypeOf<ReturnType<typeof ApiResponseCodec<C>>>;

const GetArticlesByPageResponseCodec = ApiResponseCodec(PaginationResultCodec(t.array(ArticleDTOCodec)));

export const decodeApiResponse = (res: ApiResponse<PaginationResult<ArticleDTO[]>>) => {
  return pipe(
    res,
    GetArticlesByPageResponseCodec.decode,
    E.fold(
      (e) => 'no',
      (res) => 'yes',
    ),
  );
};
```

Got error throws by `ApiResponse<PaginationResult<ArticleDTO[]>>`:

```bash
Type '{ resultList: unknown; totalItem: number; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'Mixed'.
  Type '{ resultList: unknown; totalItem: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Type<any, any, unknown>': name, is, validate, encode, and 7 more.ts(2344)
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzmYYCmcC+cBmUIhwDkOYAtDAM4D0ANsAEbU4CuAdgMYzARtEDcAKFCRYcAFRwAhpTgBRXPkIlyVOo2pzgMABZooA4eGjxJMuPDwFiPCpUOCOvSvACCsYB1poAIgBUAeQBhCAATNA44AF4LADoYAE90AAoEQTg4YFCALji2FhAGfQAadIttb1yYWJcoYDYAc1LMAEohRPQ4d24vX0DouL8ktACcAB4OtAgcLo9e-2CwiIA+IUdneAAFKQb6qW5eACU0ShZaGBDwyJixoLg0AA8YNDZQ2WqAWWAHtFDl5KcV1yQRa0WWZWqk1SZQyUBOZxgABlgC5coCIqUMhkYBAYFJaABJZ4gKqxfKFEplVprSZwba7Nj7HhsY6nc63e5PF5vOJfH5-AbVIboUZjY4wFhQNjCtATYbTOk7PYHFnw86XCK3ZbatZONguLooVmQfVoDXXOAcx7PV7vWJ837-dEcYGgqLg7HxYbQrFwdGk2r1JowuAgE6UHZoUnsZnJADa1UDjWKcXY4Rw9V+AF0WpisXC2TA0UsOHnqYJBLTXEaTibKLK7tbuXaHQKYkLhqLxZLpcM5egFdXgMbnGaS1qdRW9QaAOJoGDdTzeSgAIQS9LQI9N5oGQ639fNyXpyuZrIRh+qUigUCkCWSi-mgXNLRfa0eong0-gVyWe9ro4GZIC1yP9KDrWVj0ZFUz3ZB9vAWOMs21N1lkQMo4QlKVkFQNBkhDAs8wyOcFzmZc1w3fcxyuWIf3CQj5FiHAIFoUI8N9DJkjQFDiDYCAiHojiC24ogEhOfiQ1zMo2kETBdQ2OAoAGWi0FA8CfT9JZciIAAGcSMjDSgIwaKNiD0hS1SLNDfQLBFkVROA4xDDIkCyXIAEYU24GBKmIZ4XCILABMQTIcjgAAmTyKhMog-JgNyAsweis3onE8UJYl3O07Sy2aaTp2YtBYloCAGmSIgoC0lMoGkoA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to pass a `t.Type<ArticleDTO[]>` instead of `ArticleDTO[]` in the `ApiResponse<PaginationResult<ArticleDTO[]>>` and also wrap the `PaginationResult<...>` in the `t.Type`. Instead, you could use the actual type decoded by the codec as the type variable. Something like this.

```js
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';
import * as E from 'fp-ts/lib/Either';
import * as t from 'io-ts';

const ArticleDTOCodec = t.type({
  id: t.number,
  title: t.string,
});
type ArticleDTO = t.TypeOf<typeof ArticleDTOCodec>;

const PaginationResultCodec = <A>(codec: t.Type<A>) =>
  t.type({
    resultList: codec,
    totalItem: t.number,
  });

type PaginationResult<A> = t.TypeOf<ReturnType<typeof PaginationResultCodec<A>>>;

const ApiResponseCodec = <A>(codec: t.Type<A>) =>
  t.type({
    code: t.string,
    message: t.union([t.string, t.undefined]),
    result: codec,
  });

type ApiResponse<A> = t.TypeOf<ReturnType<typeof ApiResponseCodec<A>>>;

const GetArticlesByPageResponseCodec = ApiResponseCodec(PaginationResultCodec(t.array(ArticleDTOCodec)));

export const decodeApiResponse = (res: ApiResponse<PaginationResult<ArticleDTO[]>>) => {
  return pipe(
    res,
    GetArticlesByPageResponseCodec.decode,
    E.fold(
      (e) => 'no',
      (res) => 'yes',
    ),
  );
};
```